# How to create EC2 instance where image stored in Amazon S3 in the form of chunks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am new to the Amazon EC2 service and having some knowledge on Amazon S3 storage service. I uploaded data to s3 using multipart upload. Now my data is present in an S3 bucket. I want to create an EC2 instance from that data(data doesnot presented in the form of single image, it was stored like chunks)

How can I implement this scenario?

How to send data from S3 to AMI instance

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? It is unclear what you mean by "create an EC2 instance from that data" and "store the AMI instances". Feel free to Edit your question to add more information.

Answer (score 1):

For launching an EC2 instance you will need an Amazon Machine Image (AMI). An AMI is stored in S3 but you cannot access it directly. You can read more about AMIs [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html).

Regarding what you want to do (if I understand it correctly) you should run an EC2 instance from one of the existing AMIs (e.g. Ubuntu), configure it as you want, and create an image out of it. Later, using this image you can launch clones of that machine.